# Random sample of N unique customer IDs while ensuring the more one transacts the higher chances of being selected

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I have a table called "transaction_history", containing millions of transactions with the following columns:
column 1: customer_id
column 2: transaction date

In this table one customer may have x amount of transactions, where X >= 1

What I am looking to do is get a random sample of n (n is the number of prizes to allocate to n winners)unique customer IDs BUT ensure that the more frequent the transactions for a given customer the higher their chances of being selected a winner.

I have tried the following:
1- the straight forward dplyr::sample_n(transaction_history, size = ...) which leads to sample with duplicate customer_ids

2- Transactions %>% dplyr::distinct(customer_id) %>% dplyr::sample_n(transaction_history, size = ...) which does not give frequent customers a higher chance

3- Sampling from per customer_id groups before sampling again which also defeats this goal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the dplyr approach, could you summarize so that you get unique customerIDs with the maximum random number for that customerID?

Comment: It looks like you want n unique winners. You can add a random number to the original table, summarize the table by customerID and aggregate the random number column to the max RN. Then sort the aggregated table and select the top 10.

Comment: Thank you @freqnseverity but would that not give everyone equal probability of being chosen still? I was looking to give frequent /repeat customers a higher probability based on how frequent they are. This response is for your 1st comment. Thank you.

Comment: Customers with more transactions would absolutely have higher probability of being chosen. Consider looking at a smaller example of this and simulating the solution to see it. If you take three customers: 1 with 3 transactions, 2 with 2, and 1 with 1 transaction, you will find they each have different probabilities of being chosen.

Comment: You might consider this: if you generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each row, do you expect a customer with one transaction will have the same probability of having a number greater than .9 as a customer with five transactions? You would expect a customer with five transaction would have a better chance because they get five shots at it.

Comment: Thank you @freqnseverity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
# create some random toy data to use for example:
testdata <- 
  tibble( person_id = sample(1:5, size=20, replace=TRUE) ) %>%
  mutate( transaction_id = row_number() ) %>% 
  arrange( person_id )
```

The toy data looks like this:

```
   person_id transaction_id
 1         1              9
 2         1             11
 3         2              4
 4         2              5
 5         2              6
 6         2             10
 7         2             19
 8         3              7
 9         3             17
10         3             18
11         3             20
12         4              1
13         4              2
14         4              3
15         4              8
16         4             12
17         4             13
18         4             14
19         4             16
20         5             15
```

Now, count number of transactions per person, and use this transaction count as the *weight* in the sample_n() function:

```
testdata %>% 
  # count number of transactions per person:
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  summarise( n_transactions = n() ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  # select a random 2 people, where chance of being selected is based on number of transactions:
  sample_n( size = 2,
            weight = n_transactions
          )
```

If you run the above code-block multiple times with the same toy data, you will see that people with more transactions get selected more often.

The actual probability of selection used by the *sample_n()* function is calculated like this:
(read about it in the help documentation of the *sample_n()* function)

```
testdata %>% 
  # count number of transactions per person:
  group_by(person_id) %>% 
  summarise( n_transactions = n() ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  # calculate selection probability:
  mutate( probability_of_being_selected = n_transactions/sum(n_transactions) )
```

```
  person_id n_transactions probability_of_being_selected
1         1              2                          0.1 
2         2              5                          0.25
3         3              4                          0.2 
4         4              8                          0.4 
5         5              1                          0.05
```

Comment: Much appreciated @Joseph Bolton. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

db <- read.csv("XXXXX.csv", as.is = TRUE) #data
N <- nrow(db) #population
n <- ceiling(nrow(db)*0.1) #ceiling((1.96^2*0.5*0.5*nrow(db))/(0.02^2*(nrow(db)-1)+1.96^2*0.5*0.5)) #sample size exemple

# simple sample:
simple <- sample_n(db, n) 

# proportional stratified sample
proportional <- db %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% sample_frac(n/N)
```

Comment: Thank you @diaspv. Do you mind explaining the reason/logic behind the formula inside ceiling()  please? Thanks.

Comment: It is an example for calculating the sample size for a proportion with a 95% confidence level, a margin of error of 2% and an unknown proportion.  But you can set an arbitrary value if you want.